# python bokeh run in server side or client side

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

im a newbie so sorry if my question is silly.
Im trying to make web app that will take client input then process it and then serve it on bokeh. The process is quite heavy so im going to use AWS instance with high specification, what i want to know is if i embed bokeh to my flask then the bokeh plotting process will be run on client side or server side ? as i know there are two option "embed" and "run bokeh server", right now im using embed method and im wondering wether using bokeh server will make it faster

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, LogTicker, ColorBar
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import io

def read_DN(fname):
    inRaster = rasterio.open(fname)
    arr_DN = inRaster.read(1)
    arr_DN = arr_DN.astype('float32')
    arr_DN[arr_DN == 0] = 'nan'
    arr_DN_nan = np.isnan(arr_DN)
    return (arr_DN,arr_DN_nan)

def calculate_ndvi (fname4,fname5):
    arr_surf4,arr_DN4_nan = read_DN(fname4)
    arr_surf5,arr_DN4_nan = read_DN(fname5)

    ndvi = (arr_surf5 - arr_surf4) / (arr_surf5 + arr_surf4)

    return ndvi



def plottt(fname4,fname5,feature):
    ndvi = calculate_ndvi (fname4,fname5)
    ndvi = ndvi[3000:3500,3000:3500]
    ndvi = np.flipud(ndvi)
    if feature == 'lst' :
        plot = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), toolbar_location="right")
        color_mapper =  LinearColorMapper(palette="Spectral11", low=-1, high=1, nan_color="white")
        plot.image(image=[ndvi], color_mapper=color_mapper,
                   dh=[1.0], dw=[1.0], x=[0], y=[0])

        color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper,
                             label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))

        plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
    elif feature == 'ndvi' :
        plot = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), toolbar_location="right")
        color_mapper =  LinearColorMapper(palette="YlGn9", low=-1, high=1, nan_color="white")
        plot.image(image=[ndvi], color_mapper=color_mapper,
                   dh=[1.0], dw=[1.0], x=[0], y=[0])

        color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper,
                             label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))

        plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

    return plot
```

```
@app.route('/hasil')
def correlation_matrix():
    current_feature_name = request.args.get("feature_name")
    if current_feature_name == None:
        current_feature_name = "lst"

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('B4.TIF'):
                fname4 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file)
            if file.endswith('B5.TIF'):
                fname5 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file)

    hasil = plottt(fname4,fname5,current_feature_name)
    script, div = components(hasil)

    return render_template("index1.html", script=script, div=div)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python code will be run on the server regardless of whether you use embed or bokeh server.

> The architecture of Bokeh is such that high-level “model objects” (representing things like plots, ranges, axes, glyphs, etc.) are created in Python, and then converted to a JSON format that is consumed by the client library, BokehJS. - https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#running-a-bokeh-server

In other words, there shouldn't be much a performance difference if you're careful not to let embed block by letting it run on its own process. Usually just using a WSGI server with multiple processes such as [gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html) is enough, assuming you don't have anything else that is heavy running on Flask. If the client supports WebGL (most browsers do), then [client side rendering could be sped up using `output_backend="webgl"`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/webgl.html#accelerating-with-webgl) .

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering my question. I was excited about the WebGL but unfortunately the plotting model  that i used doesnt supported by the WebGL. Im using figure.image because i will plot huge array of float to colormap, and the documentation said that it only support circle and line. My array is 7000 x 7000 and its running so slow, i dont know if its because my laptop has no high specs, and then im wondering what if the bokeh run on client side and even if i use high specs instance in aws it will still run slowly when accessed by client with low specs laptop.

Comment: "if you're careful not to let embed block by letting it run on its own process", can you please elaborate about that ? i dont understand

Comment: Hmm maybe post a new question with a [MCVE of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Given what you have said I'm not sure if your issue is rendering the array or your array manipulations pre-rendering.

Comment: For example, if you ran Flask on one process and had multiple users access the code, then you will see a slow down.

Comment: i edited my question and put my code there, please kindly review it

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any obvious issues.